# Не работает Debug-значение в Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, отладка

> Visual Studio Community 2022 - 17.8.3

у меня не работает Debug значение, те я не вижу значение переменной

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что я пробовала:

- обновить, был какой-то пункт (Installer)
- перезагрузить комп
- выкл/вкл точки debug
- удалить точки debug
- пересобрать проект
- удалить bin/obj
- создать базовый проект с нуля
- исправить в Installer
- удалить, переустановить (проработала 2 дня и опять нет дебаг-значений)
- ["Выключить/Включить только мой код"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76587759/13754729)  в разделе "Отладка - Общие" ===> только я не все поняла, что по ссылке говорят, нужно ли в меню "Symboles" галочки поставить на два этих пункта ? у меня они не стоят
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[вот по этой ссылке была](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417036/why-the-debugger-doesnt-work), там что поняла, пробовала

вот мое меню

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*** я заметила одно странное поведение визуаль студио, если я открываю проект из папки => c =>user (solution .sln) то debug работает, а когда я открываю проект из быстрого доступа меню при открытии visualStudio то debug не работает (возможно совпадение, но сегодня утром я раза три открыла из меню, и не было дебаг-значения, а когда я открыла из папки, все отлично показывает...странно как то)

Comment: Картинку было бы лучше с русским текстом, или хотя бы английским.

Comment: сейчас работает, после выкл/вкл

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN4RQ.gif

Comment: Возможно, что вы запускали приложение в Release, а не в Debug

Comment: @OwDafuq точно приложение запускалось в Debug 1000000 процентов. Вы знаете, что странно, что так происходит переодически, и каждый раз я нахожу новое что то, пробую, потом работает какое то время, и один день утром прихожу, и на те дебаг....самое страшное как по мне.....когда есть время, вот все выше что написала делаю, а когда нету, пишу в консоли.....писать значение дебага из блазора в консоль....или там еще есть 'espionner', находишь значение....мучительно, честно, Дома все работает отлично, на работе у всех работает....началось числа 25 го декабря

Comment: Ааа, так у вас Блазор еще, там поддерживаются не все браузеры еще, кстати говоря. У меня в Opera нет дебага :) На это тоже надо внимание обратить, но в целом блазор какой-то глюченный получился немного у них :(

Comment: @OwDafuq Chrome, и если бы это было изначально, так нет же, вот только началось, а блазор с марта использую

Comment: в Opera нет дебага, надо запомнить. Ну глупо конечно